# Does the Sparkfun ESP32 Thing is compatible with generic modules like DHT11 sensor?

Tags: arduino-ide, sensors, esp32, temperature-sensor

First of all I am kind of a noob working with microcontrollers, by the way I am using **Arduino IDE 1.8.13**

I fallowed the [hookup guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/esp32-thing-hookup-guide) to set up [Arduino IDE](https://www.arduino.cc/en/software) to work with [Sparkfun ESP 32 Thing](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13907) board, and actually I was able to run the Arduino examples "Blink" and "Wifi" with no problem.

But my problem is when I tried to use the [DHT11](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/758/DHT11-Technical-Data-Sheet-Translated-Version-1143054.pdf) sensor, I did fallowed several tutorials like [this one](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-dht11-dht22-temperature-humidity-sensor-arduino-ide/) but for my bad fortune I did not succeed, instead I was getting NaN reading from the temperature and humidity sensor, at first I thought it might had something to do with the libraries version, which I installed and uninstalled several times, including the IDE, then using those same libraries I was able to do the exact same [example](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/pibots555/how-to-connect-dht11-sensor-with-arduino-uno-f4d239) on an [Arduino Uno](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-uno-rev3) microcontroller.

Then I realized I did not find any example, tutorial or document using the Sparkfun ESP32 Thing with the DHT11 sensor, since most of the examples that I found are for the generic ESP32.

Which makes me wonder, how can I know if those two components are compatible at all?

Does any one has faced something similar using ESP32 Thing with DHT11 or any another sensor?, if yes, how did you make it work or what did you do instead?

However any piece of advise is welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: An ESP32 is an ESP32 regardless of what shape board it's soldered on to.

Comment: Could it be what is not compatible is the library,? DHT sensor library by Adafruit

Comment: Unlikely. The DHT11 is pretty simple and doesn't require anything special.

Comment: Well it requires the library that I just mentioned and the dependecy to Adafruit Unified Sensorl, however do you happen to know any site or document showing those two components working together,  I wonder if sparkfun board is not very common?

Comment: There are many DHT11 libraries. Only one needs that Adafruit thing. Try using one of the simpler libraries.